# Actualizar estado estando fuera de un StateFull Widget

Tags: flutter

Buenas tardes tengan todos. De ante mano muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de ayudarme.

Cuento con un Stateful widget y dentro de él estoy utilizando un `CustomScrollView` para visualizar la información en pantalla. Dentro de mi `CustomScrollView` tengo un **`SliverPersistentHeader`** y mi lista de Slivers.

Para poder crear ese encabezado persistente cree una clase llamada *HeaderDelegate* que extiende de SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate. En ella puse los widgets que quiero que muestre el encabezado, entre esos widgets se encuentra un `DropdownButton`. Obviamente espero que cada vez que yo seleccione una opción del DropDown este se redibuje mostrando la nueva opción elegida. Pero cuando estaba por escribir el código en el atributo onChange del Dropdown me percaté de que esta clase que cree es independiente de la clase Stateful widget de mi ruta. Por lo que la función `setState()` no está disponible para que yo la ejecute desde allí :(.

Intenté lo siguiente:

```
SliverPersistentHeader _createHeader() {
  SliverPersistentHeader header;

  setState(()=> header = SliverPersistentHeader(
    delegate: HeaderDelegate(),
    pinned: true
    )
  );

return header;
  
}
```

Esta función se ejecuta en el build y es responsable de dibujar el encabezado de mi lista de Slivers.
Por alguna razón pensé que funcionaría, pero no fue así. Y ahora que lo pienso bien es claro que no funcionaría verdad jaja, porque se ejecuta junto con el build cada que vuelvo a entrar a esa ruta.

Les dejo este dato para que sepan que he hecho y qué he logrado. Ojalá haya una forma de enviar los datos de mi clase *HeaderDelegate* a la clase StateFul y desde allí mandar a redibujar cuando cambie la opción del DropDown.

Gracias de nuevo, y si necesitan más información por favor díganme y se las facilito con gusto.

**Actualización**

[image: ![Resultado deseado]

Este es el resultado que tengo en mente, como verán pensaba en usar el SliverPersistantHeader para abarcar lo que está encerrado en rojo.
¿Habrá una mejor forma de hacerlo que quizá desconozco?

Agregaré también el código con el que cuento, excluiré el que considero poco relevante para el problema:

```
class CotizacionesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CotizacionesPageState createState() => _CotizacionesPageState();
}

class _CotizacionesPageState extends State<CotizacionesPage> {
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBarView(
      children: [
        _pageOne(context),
        _pageTwo(),
      ]
    );
  }

  Widget _pageOne(BuildContext context) { // Código del 1er tab }

  Widget _pageTwo() {
    return  CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _createHeader(),
          _createBody()
      ],
    );
  }

  //? Página 2: Consultar cotizaciones
    
  SliverPersistentHeader _createHeader() {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      delegate: HeaderDelegate(),
      pinned: true
    );
  }

  Widget _createBody() {
    return SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Container(
            child: ListBody(
              children: [
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.amber),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.black),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.blue),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.amber),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.black),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.blue),
                Container(height: 150.0, color: Colors.blueGrey),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ])
    );
    }
}
```

La clase HeaderDelegate la declaré en otro archivo.

```
class HeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  String dropDownValue = 'No. de folio';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text('Buscar mediante:'),
            DropdownButton(
              value: dropDownValue,
              items: <String>['No. de folio', 'Fecha de requisición',
              'Fecha de cotización', 'Cliente', 'No. de parte']
              .map((item) 
                => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(item), value: item)).toList(),
              onChanged: (String value){
                dropDownValue = value;
                // AQUÍ llamaría el cambio de estado para redibujar, pero no se cómo hacerlo
              }
            )
          ],
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 16.0),

        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Código de búsqueda',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        ),

        SizedBox(height: 24.0),
        
        Text('Búsquedas recientes:')
      ],

    ),
  );
  }
  
  @override
  double get maxExtent => 200.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 200.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate)
  => true;

}
```

Gracias a @diegoveloper por la ayuda, pero debido a que mi clase no es Stateful no puedo llamar a setState dentro de ella :/. Disculpen si es un problema muy básico, pero gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Podrías hacerlo con un callback, crea un ejemplo sencillo, agrégalo a tu pregunta y probamos. También con inheritedwidget.

Comment: @diegoveloper , muchas gracias por tu comentario.
¿Mediante callback? ¿Podrías ser un poco más específico?, aun no logro entender para agregar información que te sea util.
Todos los cambios tendría que realizarlos dentro de la propiedad `onChange` ¿cierto? ¿agrego ese código a la pregunta?

Comment: revisa este artículo que escribí para comunicar widgets, https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c   también puedes suscribirte a mi canal para cosas más avanzadas de flutter  www.youtube.com/diegoveloper

Comment: @diegoveloper Ya estoy checando la publicación. Creo que será de mucha utilidad :). ¡Gracias! Regresaré para ver que tal me fue.

Comment: @diegoveloper , agradezco la ayuda que me ofreciste. ¡Al final sí lo conseguí! Lo hice mediante un `callback`, tal como me aconsejaste. Específicamente me ayudé de tu publicación en [medium.com](https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c) , en el apartado **Opción 1**, de la **Acción 2**.

Si alguien tiene el mismo problema que yo ¿Puedo hacer algo más para que encuentren esta publicación como ayuda?

De verdad muchas gracias, ya llevaba rato sin saber qué hacer.

Comment: Genial, deberías agregarlo como respuesta y marcarlo como resuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede solucionar mediante un callback.
Como dice @diegoveloper en [Comunicación entre Widgets:](https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c)

> Se puede crear un método en el widget Padre, y pasarlo como callback desde nuestro widget padre a nuestro widget hijo.

Para ello hay que crear un parámetro callback en nuestro widget hijo que reciba el método a ejecutar del widget padre para poder ejecutarlo desde el widget hijo.

Traté de ser explícito, espero que sea lo suficientemente claro.

Está muy bien explicado en el enlace que dejo. En el apartado **Acción 2** > **Opción 1**

Answer (score 1):

La manera recomendada de dividir una interfaz de flutter en multiples archivos es precisamente a través de Widget's mas pequeños. Puedes encapsular la lógica de HeaderDelegate en StatefulWidget o StatelessWidget. Y Para compartir estados entre el árbol de widget's debes empezar aprender a manejar el estado de tu aplicación. Puedes probar con Provider + ChangeNotifier.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo Feloo, lo tendré muy en cuenta. Tengo que aprender más sobre el manejo de estados.